# tkinter python: Want to close initial window and open new one

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, label, messagebox

I am currently working on a password manager, where the initial window will ask for login or to create a password. after clicking on login button I wanted to close that initial window and open the main password manager window. Here's my code:-

```py
# ---------------------------- Creating password/ Login ------------------------------- #

def login():

    password = my_entry.get()
    if saved_pass == password:
        # what to write here
        pass

    else:
        # when you type wrong password.
        error_label.config(text="Password didn't Match. Try Again.", fg='red')
        # error_label.place(x=160, y=330)


def create():

    password = my_entry.get()
    if len(password) > 8 and ' ' not in password:
        error_label.config(text="Your Current Password is Saved.", fg='green')
        with open('login_password.json', 'w') as add_pass:
            json.dump(password, add_pass)

    else:
        my_entry.delete(0, END)
        error_label.config(text="Password is Too Short or Not Valid.", fg='red')

# ----------------------------Initial UI SETUP ------------------------------- #


initial_window = Tk()

initial_window.title('new page')

initial_window.geometry("460x430")

initial_window.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=INITIAL_BG)

img = PhotoImage(file='new.png')

canvas = Canvas(width=360, height=250, highlightthickness=0, bg=INITIAL_BG)

canvas.create_image(210, 135, image=img)

canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

my_label = Label(text='Create Password:', bg=INITIAL_BG)

my_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

my_entry = Entry()

my_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')

my_entry.focus()

error_label = Label(text=" * Password should have at least 8 characters", fg='black', bg=INITIAL_BG)

error_label.place(x=160, y=330)

save_button = Button(text='Save', width=20)

save_button.place(x=185, y=290)

try:

    with open('login_password.json') as data:
        saved_pass = json.load(data)
        save_button.config(text='Login')
        my_label.config(text='Enter Password')
        save_button.config(command=login)
        error_label.config(text='')
except (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError, FileNotFoundError):

     SAVED = False
     save_button.config(command=create)

# ----------------------------After UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

window = Tk()
window.title('Password Manager')
window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=AFTER_BG)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just wanna ask how can I link second window to first one. I have already defined new window

Comment: You can use `Toplevel` to create new windows

Comment: Instead of destroying the first window, why not reuse it? Just delete all of the contents and then fill it up with the new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting the original window, just re-use it.

Create a function or class to create the login window, and another one to create the main program. Call the function to create the login window. When the user logs in, destroy all of the widgets for the login window and create the widgets for the main program.

This is easiest if the login window widgets all exist inside a frame. You can then destroy the frame, and all of the other widgets will automatically get destroyed. Or, you can simply loop over all of the children in the main window to destroy them:

```
for child in window.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()
```

Once you do that, the window is now empty and you can recreate it with all of the main application widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Main Window')
        self.geometry('500x300')


class LoginWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title('LoginWindow')
        self.geometry('500x300')
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.quit)

        Button(self, text='Login', command=self.login).pack()

    def login(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.parent.deiconify()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainWindow()
    root.withdraw()

    login = LoginWindow(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

MainWindow is the main window so that is why it inherits from Tk and gets withdrawn at start, it is also possible to reverse this so that the MainWindow inherits from Toplevel and then make the login window inherit from Tk but Toplevel is usually the one whos parent is Tk so it wouldn't make sense in that way. Otherwise that option is also valid. However one minor drawback is that icons in the taskbar will shift a bit when moving from LoginWindow to MainWindow, so to avoid that You can also just use frames and switch between those.

Also (I forgot) there has to be a protocol set in this case in the LoginWindow that tells what happens if window is closed. `self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.quit)` because otherwise the MainWindow will still keep running in the background (if X in the upper right corner is pressed), can also use `self.parent.destroy`

Here is the same solution but using functions:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button


def login_window(parent):

    def login():
        tp.destroy()
        parent.deiconify()

    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.title('Login Window')
    tp.geometry('500x300')
    tp.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', parent.quit)

    Button(tp, text='Login', command=login).pack()


def main_window():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Main Window')
    root.geometry('500x300')
    root.withdraw()

    login_window(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:- To kill current Window use window_name.destroy() and then call a function and initialize second window's elements into it. Thanks to and @Matiiss @Scrapper142 for guidance. You can call fucntion with button and give some arguments in it by using lambda.

**EX-** button = Button(text='click', command= lambda: function_name(arguments))

## ----------------------------After UI SETUP -------------------------------

def password_manager():

```
window = Tk()
window.title('Password Manager')
window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=AFTER_BG)

# image
logo_img = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200, highlightthickness=0, bg=AFTER_BG)
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

# website data
website_text = Label(text='Website:', bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white')
website_text.grid(row=1, column=0)

website_data = Entry(width=32, bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white', highlightcolor='red')
website_data.focus()
website_data.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

# email data
email_text = Label(text='Email/Username:', bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white')
email_text.grid(row=2, column=0)

email_data = Entry(width=51, bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white')
email_data.insert(END, 'lalitwizz21@gmail.com')
email_data.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='e')

# password data
password_text = Label(text='Password:', bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white')
password_text.grid(row=3, column=0)

password_data = Entry(width=32, bg=AFTER_BG, fg='white')
password_data.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')

# button to Generate Password
password_generator_button = Button(text='Generate Password', width=14, command=lambda: password_generator(password_data))
password_generator_button.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='e')

# button to add records
add_button = Button(text='Add', width=43, command=lambda: save_password(website_data, email_data, password_data), highlightthickness=0)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

search_button = Button(text='Search', width=14, command=lambda: search_record(website_data), highlightthickness=0)
search_button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e')

window.mainloop()
```

## ---------------------------- Creating password/ Login -------------------------------

def login():

```
password = my_entry.get()
if saved_pass == password:
    initial_window.destroy()
    password_manager()

else:
    # when you type wrong password.
    error_label.config(text="Password didn't Match. Try Again.", fg='red')
    # error_label.place(x=160, y=330)
```

def create():

```
password = my_entry.get()
if len(password) > 8 and ' ' not in password:
    error_label.config(text="Your Current Password is Saved.", fg='green')
    with open('login_password.json', 'w') as add_pass:
        json.dump(password, add_pass)

else:
    my_entry.delete(0, END)
    error_label.config(text="Password is Too Short or Not Valid.", fg='red')
```

## ----------------------------Initial UI SETUP -------------------------------

initial_window = Tk()

initial_window.title('new page')

initial_window.geometry("460x430")

initial_window.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=INITIAL_BG)

img = PhotoImage(file='new.png')

canvas = Canvas(width=360, height=250, highlightthickness=0, bg=INITIAL_BG)

canvas.create_image(210, 135, image=img)

canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

my_label = Label(text='Create Password:', bg=INITIAL_BG)

my_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

my_entry = Entry()

my_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='ew')

my_entry.focus()

error_label = Label(text=" * Password should have at least 8 characters", fg='black', bg=INITIAL_BG)

error_label.place(x=160, y=330)

save_button = Button(text='Save', width=20)

save_button.place(x=185, y=290)

try:

```
with open('login_password.json') as data:
    saved_pass = json.load(data)
    save_button.config(text='Login')
    my_label.config(text='Enter Password')
    save_button.config(command=login)
    error_label.config(text='')
```

except (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError, FileNotFoundError):

```
 SAVED = False
 save_button.config(command=create)
```

initial_window.mainloop()

Answer (score -2):

Try `initial_window.destroy()`. This closes the window and ends all of its processes. Then setting up a new variable `window = Tk()` will open a new window

Comment: this doesn't look like an answer, You should provide code, pretty poor quality

Comment: so I'll write initial_window.destroy() inside login but what about next window. I have already used window = TK()

Comment: Then it should already exist. If you don't want it to yet, put the creation of the second window in a function and call that

Comment: @Scrapper142 can You just write a code sample that would be better understandable? and explain what is sort of does